# Culture for days in Google Calendar Chart

Tags: google-visualization

How can I change the first day letter from Google Calendar Chart to match the culture? Actually the months are right.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use  `daysOfWeek: 'LMMJVSD'` in the var options of your HTML file